# constructor behaviour in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

How is this possible??
`test t2=50`??? as t2 is object a.....so how can it be equal ti an integer
using visual studio 2008

```
class test
{
public :
 int a,b;
 test(int x=0,int y=0)
 {
  a=x;
  b=y;
 }
};


void g()
{
 test t1=test(10,20);
 test t2=50;
 cout<<t1.a<<":"<<t1.b<<endl;
 cout<<t2.a<<":"<<t2.b<<endl;
}

int main()
{
 g();
 system("pause");
}
```

Comment: It is not "equal", it is an initialization. "Equal" is "==", not "=", and "=" is also used for the assignment operator but never for equality. Also please edit the question using correct English, especially punctuation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the explicit keyword in C++ mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)

Comment: @Fred: no it isn't. The OP isn't asking about the `explicit` keyword. It'd be a duplicate if someone asking this question was likely to find the other. As it is, they are different questions, even if the answer is the same.

Answer (score 8):

Since your constructor is not defined as `explicit` the compiler uses the constructor defined in `test` class to create a `test` object by passing the integer argument to the constructor (Parameter `x`). To avoid this declare the constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: OP could also make two constructors, `test(int x, int y)` and `test()`, so that `test t3(0)` wouldn't work. (This may/may not be desirable but it seems to me like I'd rather either specify both or default both, rather than wonder which one is defaulted in the one-argument version.)